# Spark on k8s: Failed to run SparkPi on cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I tried to run SparkPi on cluster mode but when it comes to reduce, it seems that executors cannot receive any resources.

I submitted my task like this:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://172.16.2.120:6443 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name spark-pi \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Never \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=ethanzhang1997/spark:test \
    local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.1.1.jar
```

And I checked the log in spark-kubernetes-driver:

```
32787 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend  - SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000000000(ns)
33285 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext  - Starting job: reduce at SparkPi.scala:38
33307 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  - Got job 0 (reduce at SparkPi.scala:38) with 2 output partitions
33308 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  - Final stage: ResultStage 0 (reduce at SparkPi.scala:38)
33308 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  - Parents of final stage: List()
33310 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  - Missing parents: List()
33316 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  - Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at SparkPi.scala:34), which has no missing parents
33417 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore  - Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.1 KiB, free 413.9 MiB)
33467 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore  - Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1816.0 B, free 413.9 MiB)
33471 [dispatcher-BlockManagerMaster] INFO  org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo  - Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on spark-pi-8670aa7a611ba783-driver-svc.default.svc:7079 (size: 1816.0 B, free: 413.9 MiB)
33474 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext  - Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1383
33492 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  - Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at SparkPi.scala:34) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1))
33494 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl  - Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks resource profile 0
34386 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
34391 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
34393 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
36448 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 2 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 3.
36451 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
36453 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
36541 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
36543 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
37594 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
37596 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
37597 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
40680 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
40685 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
40687 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
44748 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
44759 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
44762 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
46844 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
46847 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
46849 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
48525 [Timer-0] WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl  - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
48915 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 2 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 3.
48921 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
48923 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
48995 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
48998 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
53067 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
53072 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
53075 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
56125 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
56128 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
56130 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
57210 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 2 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 3.
57213 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
57214 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
57272 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
57273 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
60327 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
60329 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
60331 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
63519 [Timer-0] WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl  - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
64390 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 2 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 3.
64394 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
64395 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
64469 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
64471 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
66525 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
66531 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
66533 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
68592 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
68594 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
68595 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
71646 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
71649 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
71650 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
76720 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
76723 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
76724 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
77782 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator  - Going to request 1 executors from Kubernetes for ResourceProfile Id: 0, target: 5 running: 4.
77785 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientUtils  - Spark configuration files loaded from Some(/opt/spark/conf) : workers,spark-env.sh
77787 [kubernetes-executor-snapshots-subscribers-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicExecutorFeatureStep  - Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
78520 [Timer-0] WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl  - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

The log repeats as above, and then I check the error log in spark executor pods:

```
1254 [netty-rpc-connection-0] INFO  org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory  - Successfully created connection to spark-pi-a8d0f07a60f5ff9b-driver-svc.default.svc/192.168.3.59:7078 after 97 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
1305 [rpc-client-1-1] WARN  org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler  - Exception in connection from spark-pi-a8d0f07a60f5ff9b-driver-svc.default.svc/XXX.XXX.X.XX:7078
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1133)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
1309 [rpc-client-1-1] ERROR org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler  - Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from spark-pi-a8d0f07a60f5ff9b-driver-svc.default.svc/192.168.3.59:7078 is closed
1317 [netty-rpc-connection-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory  - Found inactive connection to spark-pi-a8d0f07a60f5ff9b-driver-svc.default.svc/192.168.3.59:7078, creating a new one.
1323 [netty-rpc-connection-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory  - Successfully created connection to spark-pi-a8d0f07a60f5ff9b-driver-svc.default.svc/192.168.3.59:7078 after 4 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
1332 [rpc-client-1-2] WARN  org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler  - Exception in connection from spark-pi-a8d0f07a60f5ff9b-driver-svc.default.svc/XXX.XXX.X.XX:7078
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1133)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
1333 [rpc-client-1-2] ERROR org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler  - Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from spark-pi-a8d0f07a60f5ff9b-driver-svc.default.svc/192.168.3.59:7078 is closed
1336 [netty-rpc-connection-2] INFO  org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory  - Found inactive connection to spark-pi-a8d0f07a60f5ff9b-driver-svc.default.svc/192.168.3.59:7078, creating a new one.
1339 [netty-rpc-connection-2] INFO  org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory  - Successfully created connection to spark-pi-a8d0f07a60f5ff9b-driver-svc.default.svc/192.168.3.59:7078 after 2 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
1350 [rpc-client-1-3] WARN  org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler  - Exception in connection from spark-pi-a8d0f07a60f5ff9b-driver-svc.default.svc/XXX.XXX.X.XX:7078
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1133)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
1351 [rpc-client-1-3] ERROR org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler  - Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from spark-pi-a8d0f07a60f5ff9b-driver-svc.default.svc/192.168.3.59:7078 is closed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1761)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$9(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:413)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcVI$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcVI$sp.java:23)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:877)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:876)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$7(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1746)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1133)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: You are getting `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer`, so connection is being actively blocked (reset) by the peer (server/client). Check if port(s) are exposed properly and connect with DevOps for checking the n/w config.